# XSLT determine year on dates

Tags: datetime, xslt

In the XSLT below, how could I only show the form (myform) if DATE_CREATED was > 12/31/2012? Essentially, I want to prevent anything before 2013 from showing the form button.

```
<xsl:template match="Table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <font face="Verdana" color="#ffffff" size="2" style="vertical-align: top; white-space: nowrap">
                <xsl:value-of select="PRG_DESCRIPTION"/>
            </font>
        </td>
        <td>
            <font face="Verdana" color="#ffffff" size="2" style="vertical-align: top; white-space: nowrap">
                <xsl:value-of select="DAYS_LEFT"/>
            </font>
        </td>
        <td>&#160;&#160;</td>
        <xsl:if test="ACTIVE = 0">
            <p>
            <td style="top: 2px">
                <form name="myform" onsubmit="popupform(this, 'join');" action="../LOS/SetCourseStart.aspx" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="CourseID">
                        <xsl:attribute name="value">
                            <xsl:value-of select="COURSE_ID"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </input>
                    <input type="hidden" name="UserID">
                        <xsl:attribute name="value">
                            <xsl:value-of select="RID"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </input>
                    <input type="hidden" name="ECode">
                        <xsl:attribute name="value">
                            <xsl:value-of select="EC"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </input>
                    <input type="hidden" name="DateCreated">
                        <xsl:attribute name="value">
                            <xsl:value-of select="DATE_CREATED"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </input>
                    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Go"/>
                    <br>           
                    </br>

                    <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
                    </SCRIPT>
                </form>
            </td>
            </p>
        </xsl:if>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the result after current transformation with data (I cannot get data before it is transformed):

```
<form name="myform" onsubmit="popupform(this, 'join');" action="../LOS/SetCourseStart.aspx" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="CourseID" value="dev^1318">
    <input type="hidden" name="UserID" value="948604">
    <input type="hidden" name="ECode" value="20080531">
    <input type="hidden" name="DateCreated" value="2008-05-31T00:00:00-06:00">
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Go">
    <br>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</form>
```

Comment: What version and processor are you using?

Comment: Assuming that you are generating HTML, you have a spurious `<p>` tag around the `<td>` tag used for the form.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Not to mention use of the `<font>` tag... _shudder_

Comment: This is very old HTML built by someone else and I'm not changing it. I'm not sure what processor it is using, how do I tell? This is a VB.Net application and instead of making a change to the VB code that gets the data, I'd rather just filter out the stuff using the already built XSLT.

Comment: `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
`

Comment: "*I cannot get data before it is transformed)*" Yes, you can: apply an *identity transform template* to it and there it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your test, add something like this (XSLT 2.0)

```
<xsl:if test="ACTIVE = 0 and year-from-date(/path/to/the/date) >= 2013">
```

I suppose that /path/to/the/date would be DATE_CREATED in your case.

Note that the function year-from-date is not readily available, it is part of the fn namespace that you need to specify with an xmlns:fn as follow:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:snap="snap:snap">
```

Comment: I get this: `'year-from-date()' is an unknown XSLT function.`

Comment: `year-from-dateTime(DATE_CREATED) >= 2013`
resulted in `'year-from-dateTime()' is an unknown XSLT function`

Comment: Ah! Yes... that's an XSLT extension. You need to add the xmlns:fn entry for that to be found by the parser. I updated my answer.

Comment: Since this seems to be 1.0, I did this an it worked: `number(substring-before(DATE_CREATED, '-')) &gt; number('2012')"`

Comment: Yeah, you did not state what version you used.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
<xsl:template match="table">
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="table[substring(DATE_CREATED, 1 , 4) > 2012]">
```

Note: this is a guess. It's very difficult to write XSLT without seeing the source XML. It's equally difficult to fix a XSLT without seeing all of it.

Comment: We just don't want the form showing, not the entire row. See my comment on @Alexis Wilke's answer.

Comment: @MB34 Well, then just add the test before the form. It seems like you did that already.